# Usage of the -al suffix on "value"

Tags: grammar, adjectives, suffixes, concision

I am trying to write the following phrase:

> Axiom about the source of value.

I cannot, however, figure out how to compact the phrase to just a few words. My mind went to using the -al suffix, and after a quick check on [a Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-al#English) to create "*valual axiom*," or alternatively "*valuar axiom*" or even "*valial axiom*."

None of these alternatives feel correct, so I was wondering if anyone knows how to properly modify "*value*" to behave as more of an adjective for an axiom.

Thank you!

Comment: “value axiom” is fine.

Comment: @Xanne The only reason I don't wish to use that is that I would like to call on the axiom later on while maintaining a specific regard for the axiom as a description of *how value is evaluated*. Value axiom on its own I feel is a bit ambiguous, especially when surrounded with the word *value* in text already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Value](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/value#h3) actually is an adjective, but it might not sound entirely natural in this use. While it's used in such phrases as *a value proposition*, that's not the case here, and a "value axiom" might not have exactly the sense you are looking for.

If you are looking for an adjective that doesn't just mean that something is about value, or will deliver value, but *how* it's valuable, how to calculate its value, or what the "source of value" is, then consider **valuational**.

From its noun form of [valuation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/valuation):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1** : the act or process of valuing
> *specifically* : appraisal of property
> **2** : the estimated or determined market value of a thing
> **3** : judgment or appreciation of worth or character

Its adjectival form would produce the following:

> A *valuational* axiom.

---

Some examples of its use include the following. I have emphasized all instances of the word.

From [*Institutional Economics: Theory, Method, Policy*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=hqrm_SUiiGIC&pg=PA168&dq=%22valuational%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibtsqqsJ7qAhWKUt8KHeKxDvIQ6AEwAXoECEcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22valuational%22&f=false), edited by Marc R. Tool:

> Tool sees the act of analysis as **valuational**. Moreover, he sees **valuational** criteria as provisional and subject to the same process of valuation as as the actual analysis of the cultural processes.

---

From [*Free Will: Critical Concepts in Philosophy*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=RfquF2_qjXwC&pg=PA30&dq=%22valuational%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibtsqqsJ7qAhWKUt8KHeKxDvIQ6AEwAnoECEgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22valuational%22&f=false), edited by John Martin Fischer:

> The possibility of unfree action consists in the fact that an agent's **valuational** system and motivational system may not completely coincide.

---

From [*Fact and Value in Emotion*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=wfs5AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA181&dq=%22valuational%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibtsqqsJ7qAhWKUt8KHeKxDvIQ6AEwBXoECFgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22valuational%22&f=false), edited by Louis C. Charland and Peter Zacher:

> Alexithymia can shed light on two main interconnecting themes of this volume. First, the designation of psychopathology includes not only a value judgment, but in fact a judgment that there is something wrong with the **valuational** aspect of a person's functioning. A clinical diagnosis is in part a **valuational** judgment of another person's capacity for making **valuational** judgments.

Comment: Thanks, that actually clarifies it a lot actually, and reminds me that I forgot the word "evaluation" exists, and thus "valuation" too. Valuation Axiom will work great!